# Array/list of hashmap?

Tags: java

I am coming from the world of Perl programming and am unfamiliar with how one would create a list of hashes in Java.

In perl, creating a list of hashes is easy.

`@rows = (
 { food=>'pizza'},
 { drink=>'coke'}
);`

Reading it out is just as easy:

`foreach my $row (@$rows){
 print $row->{food};
 print $row->{drink};
}`

How would one accomplish something similar in Java? Either with just strings, or also with the possibility of objects as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following is roughly equivalent to your Perl code.

```
List<Map<String,String>> mapList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
Map<String,String>> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
map1.put("food", "pizza");
Map<String,String>> map2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
map2.put("drink", "coke");
Collections.addAll(mapList, map1, map2);

...

for (Map<String,String> map : mapList) {
    System.out.println("food is " + map.get("food"));
    System.out.println("drink is " + map.get("drink"));
}
```

However, as you can see this is a lot more cumbersome than in Perl.  Which brings me to the point that it is usually a better idea to do this kind of thing in Java using custom classes instead of associative arrays (e.g. `Map` instances).  Then you can write this as something like:

```
List<Diet> dietList = new ArrayList<Diet>();
Collections.addAll(dietList, new Diet("pizza", null), new Diet(null, "coke");

...

for (Diet diet : dietList) {
    System.out.println("food is " + diet.getFood());
    System.out.println("drink is " + diet.getDrink());
}
```

This approach (using a custom class) is generally more robust, more efficient, and gives you more readable code.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Map<String,String>> mapList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>()
```

Without code you've tried or more specification I can just provide an example of what you're 
looking for.  Ask more specifics and I can provide more info.

To iterate over the list:

```
for (Map<String, String> map : mapList) {
    String value = map.get("food");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually in java is quite long compared to perl :(

To create:

```
List<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

Map value1 = new HashMap();
value1.put("foo", "pizza");
list.add(value1);

Map value2 = new HashMap();
value2.put("drink", "coke");
list.add(value2);
```

To read:

```
for (Map<String,String> element : list) {
  // print keys and values
}
```

If you want something more dynamic and still have access to java libraries you can use something like groovy (or scala or clojure).